# Python Youtube Data API 3.0 request error

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use the YouTube Data API to retrieve information about a video, including how many times it has been added to playlists, including the "Favorites" playlist.

To do this, I make an API request to the following endpoint:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

So, I have the following code inside **"youtube_api.py"**:

```
import requests

# Set your API key and video ID
api_key = "API key here"
video_id = "HR8pgFOJRlY"

# Send the API request
  url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics&id={video_id}&key={api_key}"
  response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
data = response.json()

# Retrieve the playlistAdds count from the statistics object
playlist_adds = data["items"][0]["statistics"]["playlistAdds"]

print(f"The video has been added to playlists {playlist_adds} times.")
else:
print("Error occurred while making the API request.")
```

I open a terminal or command prompt, and run the following command:

```
python youtube_api.py
```

And I get:

```
Error occurred while making the API request.
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I troubleshoot why I get that error message?

Thanks!

Comment: You can add more logging to your code like what the status code was and what response you got  `print(response.status_code)` & `print(response.text)` so you have more context. PS I really hope its not a real API key you have posted here.